# hover effect and function in jquery 

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a goal `<div class="outter">`  and another `<div class="inner">`  as tooltip,

```
<div class="outter"></div>
<div class="inner"></div>
```

in default the tooltip is  invisible , when I mouse hover on the "outter",the "inner" will appear in the "outter" one ,until mouse out the "outter" , the "inner" will disppear.

```
$(".outter").hover(function(){
   var $top=$(".outter").offset().top;
   var $left=$(".outter").offset().left;

   $('.inner').css({'top':$top+10+'px','left':$left+10+'px'}).show();
},function(){
    $('.inner').hide();
})
```

but when the mouse have not move out from the "outter" ,at the same time mouse on the "inner" in "outter",**the problem happened:  the inner one flashed, not stable**

[the online case here](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/5QMfk/)

So what's wrong with the case ?

I want the inner one would stable ,not the flashed.Please help,thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an option, the easiest solution is to use your elements like they're named:

```
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

...then your current code works fine, since the `mouseleave` won't trigger when entering the `.inner` element, since it's a child.  [You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5QMfk/3/).

Comment: I know the "inner" in "outter" will solve the problem,but there are lots of div in my page,the tooltip will adapter to each div,so if each div has a tooltip, I think it is not good……

Comment: @hh54188 - what's the issue with putting them inside?  If you *don't*, you should at the very least rename the classes used :)

Comment: Putting them inside is no problem.What I mean is that each div in my page need a tooltip,and lots of them are common.So if I set a tooltip in each div,it a waste of html code……:)put you remind me ,I can use the "appendTo" to append to the div I need first,then execute the hover function……

Comment: @hh54188 - yup, many ways to solve the uniqueness problem, I'm just unaware of all your constraints, your example is quite simplified :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the ideal solution but try this one

```
$(".outter, .inner").hover(function(){
   var $top=$(".outter").offset().top;
   var $left=$(".outter").offset().left;

   $('.inner').css({'top':$top+10+'px','left':$left+10+'px'}).show();
},function(){
    $('.inner').hide();
})
```

[`updated demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5QMfk/1/)